# Why are all the SAS capabilities unlocked from the start in career mode?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Recently, I started to play KSP again, and I noticed that even though I used the most realistic settings to make the game challenging, *right from the start* I get **all** the SAS capabilities unlocked even with Jebediah being only LVL 0.

Is this some kind of new feature? I can't find an option to disable this anywhere.

Comment: Actually it *was* a kind of feature [since a long time ago](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Specialization#No_experience_specialization_override) with the "kerbal experience enabled" setting. The 1.11.1 bug seems to ignore this setting...

Comment: There also is a setting about "All SAS capabilities on all modules." Check if it is on or not. I believe it is in advanced settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found it, this is a [bug](https://bugs.kerbalspaceprogram.com/issues/27162) with the 1.11.1 version. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.